# OpenCV : io_win32.cc : _wfopen has not been declared MinGW

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw

I am trying to build `OpenCV` from source using `TDM MinGW (5.1.0)` shipped along with `code blocks (32 bit)` and `CMake`, while running `mingw32-make` I am getting  `io_win32.cc : _wfopen has not been declared` error.

```
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  5%] Built target libjpeg-turbo
[  7%] Built target libtiff
[ 15%] Built target libwebp
[ 18%] Built target libjasper
[ 19%] Built target libpng
[ 24%] Built target IlmImf
[ 24%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/io_win32.cc.obj
D:\Programs\OpenCV-Source\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs\io_win32.cc: In function 'FILE* google::protobuf::internal::win32::fopen(const char*, const char*)':
D:\Programs\OpenCV-Source\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs\io_win32.cc:330:10: error: '::_wfopen' has not been declared
   return ::_wfopen(wpath.c_str(), wmode.c_str());
          ^
3rdparty\protobuf\CMakeFiles\libprotobuf.dir\build.make:258: recipe for target '3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/io_win32.cc.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/io_win32.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:715: recipe for target '3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After googling for a while I found [this link](https://github.com/mosra/corrade/issues/35) which pointed out that `wfopen`  is defined under `wchar.h`

```
#ifdef __MSVCRT__
_CRTIMP wchar_t* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fgetws (wchar_t*, int, FILE*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fputws (const wchar_t*, FILE*);
_CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  getwc (FILE*);
_CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  getwchar (void);
_CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  putwc (wint_t, FILE*);
_CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  putwchar (wint_t);
#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
_CRTIMP wchar_t* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _getws (wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _putws (const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   _wfdopen(int, const wchar_t *);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   _wfopen (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   _wfreopen (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, FILE*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   _wfsopen (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, int);
_CRTIMP wchar_t* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _wtmpnam (wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP wchar_t* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _wtempnam (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _wrename (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _wremove (const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    _wperror (const wchar_t*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   _wpopen (const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
#endif  /* __STRICT_ANSI__ */
#endif  /* __MSVCRT__ */
```

I am not sure how and where to add that `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` option they are talking about in the link.
Anyway, Can anyone help me to solve this issue ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "how and where to add that `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` option" - Open (in any text editor) file `CMakeCache.txt`, located in the build directory, find `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable and add given option to its value. Then rerun `cmake` and `mingw32-make`. This way may do not give desired effect (e.g. if the option will be cancelled by the option in `CMakeLists.txt` script. But if it works, then it is better than modifying system headers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I guess you are right, if I put that flag in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, then it works. Using my way it was cumbersome as many of the methods were non ANSI and I was having a lot of errors and warnings afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how could I possibly have made it simpler and I got voted down for not simplifying it.
Anyway,  In `wchar.h` if i put `#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__` by removing `#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__`, it ran perfectly. I don't know whether this is a correct way to do or no but it worked !

### UPDATE

Above method does works but since there are a lot of non-ANSI methods used in the opencv source files, the compiler starts complaining every time it encounters such methods. So, its better to set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-U__STRICT_ANSI__` flag in `CMakeCache.txt` where we are building our sources. This way its more appropriate and less cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I am also building OpenCV and have the same problem. First I look at the file io_win32.cc:

```
FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char* mode) {
#ifdef SUPPORT_LONGPATHS
  if (null_or_empty(path)) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return NULL;
  }
  wstring wpath;
  if (!as_windows_path(path, &wpath)) {
    errno = ENOENT;
    return NULL;
  }
  wstring wmode;
  if (!strings::utf8_to_wcs(mode, &wmode)) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return NULL;
  }
  return ::_wfopen(wpath.c_str(), wmode.c_str()); //the error
#else
  return ::fopen(path, mode);
#endif
}
```

It seems that that fopen can be used instead of _wfopen by disabling SUPPORT_LONGPATHS in the same file io_win32.cc:

```
// Comment this out to fall back to using the ANSI versions (open, mkdir, ...)
// instead of the Unicode ones (_wopen, _wmkdir, ...). Doing so can be useful to
// debug failing tests if that's caused by the long path support.
#define SUPPORT_LONGPATHS
```

If you curious about SUPPORT_LONGPATHS: https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10 . Basically, it supports long file name upto 32,767 characters.